# IE11 Flexbox column container with content that overflows and footer always at bottom - content will not overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I found similar issues reported for Flexbox in IE11, but none of them were exactly like mine.

Problem: Container positioned in the center of screen, with set width and max-height. Inside the container there's a div for content (set with to flex-shrink and to overflow:auto) and a div for footer (flex-shrink disabled). In IE11, when the window cannot fit the content, the container overflows and the div for content does not show vertical scrollbar. On Chrome, Edge and Firefox it works properly.

Related codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggqpEz

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Some content
    Large content
    Large content
    Large content
    Large content
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;

  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 10%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Have you got any ideas?
Setting max-height on content div to ie. 70vh causes it to show scrollbar when window is small, but it's not really a solution.